# Can someone tell me what is wrong with this java script?

Tags: javascript, jscript

I wrote this script but it think something is wrong with the syntax since it wont execute could you please tell me whats wrong?

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    var subcategoriesUrl = '@Url.Action("GetSubCategories")';
    var subcategories = $('#SelectedSubCategory');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SelectedCategory').change(function () {
            subcategories.empty();
            $.getJSON(subcategoriesUrl, { idSubCategory: $(this).val() },function(data) {
                if (!data) {
                    return;
                }
                subcategories.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Hello'));
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    subcategories.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                });
            });
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the Console in your developer tools or http://jshint.com/ to see what is wrong with the syntax. Use

Comment: That indentation is terrible.  Five `});` tacked on at the end?  No wonder you can't find the problem.  I threw it in jsfiddle and had it format the code.  Looks like you might have one too many `});` at the end: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjx7h5p/, but I can't tell for certain if that is really why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`type="text/jscript"` should be `type="text/javascript"` and there is an extra `});` at the end

Comment: thank you. I modified it but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have added one `});` too much.